# Ajax actionLink onSuccess get data which is in html format

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Ajax helper class which calls controller which in turn controller returns PartialViewResult with Model data, the `PartialViewResult` renders `IEnumerable`. I want to get one ID from the Model returned from `PartialViewResult`, I 'm not sure how to do that I even used `TempData` but it didn't work so `AjaxLink` has `OnSucesss` method which gets data however that data is in html format so I need something which gets ID from the Model and assign it to the `Actionlink` (please check last statement of Parent View)

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetContacts(string q, int limit = 5, int p = 1, int per_page = 5)
{

    return PartialView("DateRange2_Partial", Model);
}
```

**ParentView**

```
<div class="col-xs-6" id="DepartmentDetails">                                                 
    @Html.Partial("DateRange2_Partial",Model)
</div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("click me",
    "GetContacts",
    "Home",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "DepartmentDetails",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnSuccess = "OnAjaxRequestSuccess"
    }
)



<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnAjaxRequestSuccess(data) {
        // Get value from data and pass it to the Action link?
    }
<script/>

@Html.ActionLink("Redirect", "Action", new { SingleDatePicker = ***Assign value here from Ajax action link***})
```

**PartialView**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.drr)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRange1)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways - one would be to include an element in your partial say `<div id="myvalue" data-id="yourValue"></div>` and in the `OnSuccess` function - `var value = $('#myvalue').data('id');` But you cannot use `ActionLink()` the way you are - its razor code which is parsed on the server  and the value you want does not exist at that point. You would need javascript to update the `href` of your link

Comment: But its a bit unclear what your wanting to do here. Why not just include the link within the partial your returning?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Didn't get you, I need to get the value from OnAjaxRequestSuccess(data) as if now data comes in HTML format so I want to get just the ID value, what I 'm trying to do here is filtering the results using Ajax link and post filtering I get a unique ID so I want that ID to pass from the Actionlink to the controller, I don't know any better way to achieve what I' m trying to do.

Comment: I have already suggested that your partial view include a element with a `data-` attribute which you can then read from the DOM in your `OnAjaxRequestSuccess(data)` function

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry I 'm not getting your code what should be "yourValue" and how the ajax and div are associated? Also if I set TempData on partialView Controller and try to get the TempData value in Parent View it doesn't work any reasons?

Comment: An ugly solution, but in your `GetContacts()` add `ViewBag.ID = xxx;` In the partial add `<div id="myvalue" data-id=@ViewBag.ID></div>`. In the `function OnAjaxRequestSuccess(data) {` add `var id = $('#myvalue').data('id');` and then use that to update the `href` attribute of your link. But I stll do not understand why you don't just generate the link in your partial view

Comment: I got your first comment what you were trying to say. Do you mean actionlink() in PartialView ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164259/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-pathp).