# Refresh list and not page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where on the left side of the page there are links and in the center, there is a table so I have to refresh the table based on the link selected however it should not refresh page, I opted for Ajax action link, however, there are issues post the implementation and I realised that is not good from design perspective so could you please help me with some solution possibly code to achieve my requirement.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("click me",
    "GetContacts",
    "Home",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "DepartmentDetails",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnSuccess = "OnAjaxRequestSuccess"
    }
)
```

Comment: So what is happening with current code ? Are you getting any issues ? Specific errors ?

Comment: The problem with this code is I have a partial view so when I click on Ajax link, it will go to controller which filters data, takes temp ID into the models property now here is the problem, I want to take that ID to parent view to be used in Action Link.

Comment: If clicking on the link is doing a normal navigation, it means you do not have the needed js files included in the page  for making the links ajaxified. Did you include those files ?

Comment: There is no issue over there if you see my comment I 'm asking how to take a value from partial view to parent view basically the one which is assigned in partial view controller

Comment: You need to share the relevant code and what is your expected behavior (with some examples would be great). I still do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538760/ajax-actionlink-onsuccess-get-data-which-is-in-html-format?noredirect=1#comment84079128_48538760

Comment: You can always use a jQuery selector to get any attribute value from your DOM element. So after you update the DOM element inside `OnAjaxRequestSuccess`, you may try read the DOM element you are interested in and get's it's corresponding attribute value

Comment: Yes, I have done the same however that is bad architecture/solution so that's the reason I posted a question to get a better solution and if there is any replacement of ajax action link.

Comment: You could also return a JSON respons which has 2 properties, one is your specific value and second is the string version of the view result you want to use to update DOM.

Comment: Do you have any code reference?

Answer (score 0):

Move the table to a partial view and load it on click of the link. This will just refresh the partial view instead of the entire master page.

Comment: Yes already used that approach and for that reason, I used Ajax action link, however, I need some better solution keeping the table in partial view.

Comment: Can you post the code of the page which has the link and the table please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Ajax. It doesn’t required  to refer any additional script for partial load.

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "DepartmentDetails" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("deptName ");
    <input type="submit" value="List Department" id="btnList" />
    <div id="divDepartmentDetails"></div>
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#btnList").click(function (event) { 
              $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("Department"))", 
                type: "GET",
                data: { deptName: $("deptName").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                     $("#divDepartmentDetails").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing  while doing this On success, if I want a particular ID in response and using that ID I want to pass as a parameter to the ActionLink how to get that one particular ID